# Connecting to WinCE Device from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I have a WinCE device. Is it possible to connect to the device from visual studio to view the following

```
Folder structure. 
Applications running. 
Registry values.
```

Is there any other ways to view these items?

Where can I get more information on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Folder structure.

Remote File Viewer

> Applications running.

Remote Process Viewer or Remote Spy

> Registry Values.

Remote Registry Editor

[image]

**EDIT:**

If your device does not have ActiveSync, you should read this MSDN article on [how to connect to Windows CE without ActiveSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708.aspx)

Summary of the MSDN article:

**Prepare the device:**
Copy the following files to the \Windows\ folder on the device. These files are located on the development computer by default at \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target\wce400\.

```
  Clientshutdown.exe

  ConmanClient2.exe

  CMaccept.exe

  eDbgTL.dll

  TcpConnectionA.dll
```

run conmanclient2.exe on the device

Determine the IP address of the device.

**Prepare Visual Studio:**
On the Visual Studio Tools menu, click Options, then click Device Tools, and then click Devices.

Select Windows CE Device, and then click Properties.

To the right of the Transport box, click Configure.

In the Configure TCP/IP Transport dialog box, select Use specific IP address, and then type the device IP address.

Close the dialog boxes and soft-reset the device if needed

**Set security and establish the connection:**
At the command prompt on the device, run cMaccept.exe.

Within three minutes, connect to the device. If you establish your first connection within three minutes, you can continue deploying and debugging indefinitely as long as you are using the same Visual Studio instance. You can eliminate the cMaccept step by disabling security on the device. To do so, use the Remote Registry Editor to set HLKM\System\CoreConOverrideSecurity = 1 DWORD value.

Comment: Can I view these things through a COM port and the TCP/IP connection?

Answer (score 1):

If the OEM have included Activesync support you should be able to connect it via USB (assuming the device has USB) and see the device in the Windows Mobile Device Centre.  You may also need to install OEM specific USB drivers.  If no USB you may be able to Activesync over Bluetooth or Infra-red.

You can see folder structure through Mobile Device Centre.  Visual Studio (up to 2008) includes the **Remote Registry Editor** and the **Remote Process Viewer**, which should get you the rest.

Answer (score -1):

copy all file files same on address 
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target\wce400\[armv4i]` this is name my device
to 
device windows root and some time device need reset
so, you must run `CMAccept.exe` and `ConmanClient2.exe`
good luck and thanksm for start this discution
:)