# how to bring up start menu in windows mobile 6.5 app (full screen) in vb.net compact

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, taskbar, windows-mobile-6.5

My app is built in vb.net compact. All these years in all versions when user taps at the top or bottom of the screen (depending on where the task bar is located) it brings up the task bar and start menu fine. But now the latest OS build doesn't do it anymore. I'm thinking of having a button in my app to bring up the task bar but not sure how to do it.

However, in IE full screen there is a circular button that brings up the task bar. If I can accomplish it in my app that would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Remote Spy tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127349/connecting-to-wince-device-from-visual-studio/6127456#6127456) to find out the name of your task-bar, then you can try calling [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function using this name to get the handle, and finally calling [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get it to show. (In P/Invoke versions for [FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.FindWindowW) and [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/showwindow.html) use `coredll.dll` instead of `user32.dll`).