# Install WinCe 6.0 os on vortex86 based device

Tags: operating-system, windows-ce, builder, platform

I need to install WinCe 6.0 on Vortex86 device and then write application to it.

I used Platform Builder and built OS based on Vortex86 BSP. How can I install it on my Vortex based device? (It has USB and I have disk on key to install on it)

How can I connect to it and run the applications on it using VS2005?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate questions here.

First, "installing" CE depends on the bootloader in use.  You need to put an NK.BIN wherever the bootloader is looking. You might be able to use [`diskprep`](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DiskPrep) to make the USB device bootable and run the image right from it.  Maybe it has internal storage and uses [`loadcepc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448680.aspx) to load NK.bin off of that. Those are the two ways the Vortex86 devices I've used operate, but which yours uses we can only guess at.

As for connecting and debugging an application, that's been asked and answered several times.  [Here's just one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127349/connecting-to-wince-device-from-visual-studio).

Comment: I used diskprep to make usb device bootable and when I turn it on I saw a screen with wince and after 30 seconds, the screen become black and nothing happened (I wait couple of minutes). The led of my disk on key kept lighting, but nothing on my screen.

Comment: Did you look at the debug output from the device?  My bet is you have KITL enabled in the OS image and aren't connecting with Platform Builder, so the OS boot is waiting for you to connect.  Turn off KITL in the build and it will probably run fine.

Comment: You were right so I disabled it. Now only "eboot space in memory" and "kernel debugger" enable. Does it right?

Comment: It fails to work: nothing happens - black screen. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: There's no way I can diagnose it remotely.  Check that the BIOS settings are right for the boot media and check the debug output.  That's the only guidance I can give.

Comment: The original OS runs well, so probably it's not the bios. What is "debug output"? If I try to build OS empty (uncheck all the components). Should it run well?